# stateless session api request

Tags: express, authentication, jwt, express-jwt, stateless-session

I am building a simple app that uses JWT for authentication. But I keeps on getting the error saying the route I `GET` to require a call back function.

**What do I expect?**

I should be getting the current user's data back.

**What do I actually get?**

Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]

**Route:**

```
const authenticate = require("../middlewares/authenticate");
const usersController = require("../controllers").users;

app.get("/users/me", authenticate, usersController.getMe);
```

**Model:**

```
"use strict";
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var User = sequelize.define(
    "User",
    {
      email: DataTypes.STRING,
      password: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    {
      classMethods: {
        associate: function(models) {
          // associations can be defined here
        },
        findByToken: function(token) {
          const User = this;
          let decoded;

          try {
            decoded = jwt.verify(token, "leogoesger");
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }

          return User.find({ where: { email: decoded.email } });
        }
      }
    }
  );
  return User;
};
```

**Middleware:**

```
const { User } = require("../models/user");

const authenticate = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("called here");
  const token = req.header("x-auth");
  User.findByToken(token)
    .then(user => {
      if (!user) {
      }

      req.user = user;
      req.token = token;
      next();
    })
    .catch(e => {
      res.status(401).send(e);
    });
};

module.exports = { authenticate };
```

**Controller:**

```
module.exports = {
  getMe(req, res) {
    res.status(200).send({ message: "hello" });
  }
};
```

Comment: Show us how you import the modules with `authenticate` and `getMe` in it.  I'm guessing you aren't doing that properly so when you think you have the function you want, you don't.  Also, please add the exact wording of the error message.

Comment: imported is added. error message is on there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your authenticate module exports an object, yet you do this:

```
const authenticate = require("../middlewares/authenticate");
```

which means your `const authenticate` is an object, not your function.  Change that to this:

```
const authenticate = require("../middlewares/authenticate").authenticate;
```

Or, change the module to export the function directly instead of exporting an object with the function in it.